# How can a custom listview communicate back to the fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-custom-view

I have a dynamic list view (gesture based drag & rearrange) which is based on the [custom list view](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q) from devbytes. In a Fragment I set up this custom list view.

```
private DynamicListView mListView;
...
```

This list view is set with values (Tasks):

```
mListView.setListValues(mTaskList);
```

This mTaskList is also modified e.g. when a task is deleted via swipe. This happens outside the DynamicListView.

Whenever the order of tasks is changed in DynamicListView it needs to be communicated back to the Fragment. Due to a lack of knowledge/experience I don't know how the custom DynamicListView can let the fragment know which tasks have swapped the positions. From the DynamicListView:

```
private void swapElements(ArrayList<TaskLineItemObject> arrayList,
        int indexOne, int indexTwo) {

    TaskLineItemObject temp = arrayList.get(indexOne);
    arrayList.set(indexOne, arrayList.get(indexTwo));
    arrayList.set(indexTwo, temp);
    // NOW INFORM THE FRAGMENT ON THIS SWAP
}
```

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: You can try a listener in your fragment, pass that listener to your list, and trigger that listener from your swapElements method.

Comment: swapElements is called for each swap. Lets assume you have five tasks in the list. Now the second task is moved before the fifth task. So the swap happens for 2 & 3 (1,3,2,4,5) and then 2 & 4 (1,3,4,2,5). The listener returns after the first swap and the swap does not get completed. Right now I am trying to collect the swap indexes and use a listener when the touch motion ends. Even if I can get it working I am not sure this is a good approach.